# Facebook FB.ui apprequest not showing on mobile

Tags: facebook, jquery-mobile, facebook-javascript-sdk, fb.ui

I am developing a mobile app with facebook integration. The app is developed with jquery mobile(see below)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
```

I've managed so far to integrate Facebook functionality with Facebook JSSDK and in normal browser all works, as it should(login, logout, other api calls), but when i try to send an apprequest with:

```js
function sendRequest() {
    FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', message: 'Are you ready?',
    }, function(response) {
    console.log('sendRequest response: ', response);
    if (response && response.to) {
      for (var j = 0; j < response.to.length; j++) {
    alert('You have: ' + response.response.name + ' with User id: ' + response.to[j] + ' invited');
        //alert(response.to[j]);
      }
    } else {
            console.log('User didn't invite anyone');       
        }
});
```

on a mobile the request dialog doesn't pop up. I see only a blank white screen.
Does anyone have an idea what am i doing wrong?

Comment: So what is the answer? I'm having similar issue.

Comment: i am having similar issue too...

Answer (score 0):

after trying few things, seems like the problem is with the mobile's page height and where the dialog is being positioned on the screen.

I used the following to fix on my nexus5:

Added a page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="fb-page">
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#fb-page {
    position: initial;
}
```